# radio button toggle slideUp slideDown

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript:

```
$("body").on('click', '#bhexperience', function () {
       // alert('fsdf');
        $(".hidePanel").slideDown('slow');
        //$(".tooltip").hide();
        //$(".block-conent").removeClass('block-conent');
        //$(this).parent().parent().find('.tooltip').show();
        //$(this).parent().parent().addClass('block-conent');
        //$(this).addClass('newContent');
    });
```

How do I make this .slideUp when unselected?

Here is the aspx page html in case that helps:

```
<ul class="textinput reason gridA">
  <li><p class="feedback"><label><input runat="server" type="radio" name="feedbackreason[]" aria-label="What would you like to tell us about?" aria-valuetext="Your Baptist Health experience" title="What would you like to tell us about?: Your Baptist Health experience" id="bhexperience"  class="feedbackreason reqType" value="bd" clientidmode="Static" /> Your Baptist Health experience</label></p></li>
  <li class="block panel-content marginT20">
      <div class="hidePanel" style="display:none">
      <p class="hl4">To enable us to respond to your comments, would you please let us know who to contact?</p>
      <p class="marginT10 marginL10"><label for="feedbackName" class="alignL">Name:</label><input type="text" name="feedbackName" id="feedbackName" class="text feedbackName marginL5" title="feedback Name" /><br />
      <br />
      <label for="contactInfo" class="alignL">Contact Information:</label><input type="text" name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" class="text contactInfo marginL5" title="Contact Information" /></p>
      <p class="hl4 marginT10">For immediate patient portal service, please call
      <br />
      <strong><a class="phoneCall" style="color: mediumvioletred" href="tel:18446220622">1.844.622.0622</a></strong> (toll-free, 24/7)</p>       
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you include your html?

Comment: Please add an example on fiddle and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event in jQuery:

```
$('#bhexperience').on('blur', function() {
    $(".hidePanel").slideUp('slow');
});
```

EDIT: See my updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2wbu0vd/1/).

```
$('.textinput.reason input:radio').on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'bd' ) {
        $(".hidePanel").slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(".hidePanel").slideUp('slow');
    }
})
```

Comment: Post a jsfiddle, and I can assist further.

Comment: Thank you I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: See my updated jsfiddle, and my updated answer @AprilSmallwood